# 2 columns unique in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, alter-table, unique-index

Is it possible to make a 2 coulmns unique in mysql db?
for example:

```
ID | columnA | columnB
 1 | Dan     | 1
 2 | Dan     | 2
 3 | Zak     | 1
 4 | Dan     | 1 (WHEN TRYING TO INSERT ROW 4 - NOT ALLOWED! DUPLICATE COULMNA + COLUMNB)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD UNIQUE INDEX idxColAB (columnA, columnB)
```

Comment: this will just make the combination of those items unique, i think he wants uniqueness define by col1 != col2

Comment: @PlantTheIdea he actually says in the sample `COLUMNA + COLUMNB`

Comment: This is the correct solution based on the sample data he gave.

Answer (score 0):

A unique index guarantees that the index key contains no duplicate values and therefore every row in the table is in some way unique. There are no significant differences between creating a UNIQUE constraint and creating a unique index that is independent of a constraint. Data validation occurs in the same manner, and the query optimizer does not differentiate between a unique index created by a constraint or manually created. However, creating a UNIQUE constraint on the column makes the objective of the index clear

[link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187019.aspx)